# Using async returns one item instead of multiple

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using an ASP.NET 6 Core MVC web app.

I've been migrating from Webforms to MVC so a little rusty in some areas.

I'm trying to understand `async` and `await` usage (gone through a few tutorials and although it makes some sense, I need to tinker around with it a little).

I have some code written which is not async and decided to try to change it over.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var results = await collection.FindAsync(_ => true);

    foreach (var item in results.ToList())
    {
        await Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(item);
    }

    return View();
}
```

So without using async and await, I get a list of items but when using the above code only the first element is shown in the browser.

Is it possible to use async in this manner or am i missing something to get this working this way?

Edit (code that display all items in the list without async)

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var results = collection.Find(_ => true);

    foreach (var item in results.ToList())
    {
        Response.WriteAsync(item);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: "Shown" where?  To start, using `Response.Write` *at all* in MVC is... strange.  Why not provide the data to the view as a model?  When you debug, what specifically happens?  When debugging, what do you observe `results` to contain?  How many times do you observe the loop to iterate?  Where/how are you observing the output?

Comment: Can you share the code without async and await here?

Comment: Original thread edited

Comment: The documentation is not perfectly clear, but it looks like `WriteAsJsonAsync` is a one-shot operation, meaning it writes the entire response instead of appending.

Comment: ```FindAsync``` returns single element. If you want to retrieve all entities just use ```Where``` and ```ToListAsync```

Comment: Also, to my mind you can simply do this
 ```public async IActionResult Index()
{
    return View(await collection.ToListAsync())
}```

Comment: @KęstutisRamulionis as far as i can tell `FindAsync(_ => true)` will return all records. The criteria here indicates to return all records.

Comment: To say you are "rusty" usually implies that you are returning to something that you were once very good at, but over the time you haven't used it you've forgotten some of it. Is that the case here?

Comment: As https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset.findasync?view=entity-framework-6.2.0 states: ```Returns
Task<Object>
A task that represents the asynchronous find operation. The task result contains the entity found, or null.```

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using an async method for appending to the response in your current code without awaiting it (which is a bad idea btw) the async Index()-Method should look something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var results = await collection.FindAsync(_ => true);

    foreach (var item in results.ToList())
    {
        await Response.WriteAsync(item);
    }

    return View();
}
```

using WriteAsJsonAsync serializes whatever object you throw into it to json and sets the whole response Body - it doesn't append.

So the issue here doesn't lie within the switch to async but rather the used method.